# Падеж в местоимении "некого"

Tags: падежи

> Ждать было некого.

Я здесь определил винительный падеж, у методиста - родительный.
Ждать (кого/что) его.
Ждать (кого/что) вино.
Не понимаю, на каком основании тут пишут Р.п?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Винительный допустим, но родительный лучше. Раньше вообще только он и употреблялся: *ждать автобуса, его прихода, вина.*